# How can i reset my autorization every time i relaunch the app Android

Tags: android

I want to know how i can reset my autorisation every time a user relaunch the app if it's possible because i have a module who need for every launch of the app my permission needs to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but, maybe you can use the lifecycle of the activity, request auth everytime activity changes to onPause onResume etc.

Answer (score 0):

In onDestroy() method of parent activity, clear your auth, and in onStart() method of  activity check whether the auth is empty/cleared, and if it is empty ask user to re-authorize.

Comment: By auth do you mean permission like READ_PHONE_STATE ? If yes how do i clear that ?

Comment: Pardon me, Are you asking for app permissions? like storage or camera permission.

Comment: This would also cause it to reauth every time they rotate the device, change the locale, etc.  Since activities on the backstack may be destroyed and recreated, it may even occur when hitting the back button.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want  to clear all the data of the app, use this line inside `onDestroy()` of the activity:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        (getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager).clearApplicationUserData()
    }
```

And when user opens the app again, everything will be fresh, all allowed permissions will be revoked and all data will be cleared

Comment: Do i put it in my androidManifest or in a build gradle file ?

Comment: You have to add the above piece of code inside your activity/fragment